Dropping a row in a python dataframe
I converted a binary string variable to 0s and 1s, but somehow I ended up with an instance of 0.5289256. I am trying to remove that one row, with several ways I have found online, but it is still there:
OG_df_dropped = OG_df.query("type != 0.528926 ")
unique_values = OG_df_dropped ['type'].unique()
print(unique_values)
[0.         0.52892562 1.   

 ]

I have also tried this:
i = OG_df[((OG_df.type == 0.528926 ) )].index 
print(i)
OG_df.drop(i)

Again, same results
What am I missing or doing wrong?

Instead of removing the row, figure out why you're getting it and fix that.

I think that's a string that contains 0.5289256, it's not just that value by itself.

Please post a [mre] that shows how you're creating the dataframe.

You could initialize a small example OG_df that shows the problem. You only need the type column and a handful of rows. That gives people who answer a script to work from.

I tried below in Jupyter and works fine. Please let me know incase it doesn't work, I suspect something to do with floating-point precision. I can try other ways to help!!
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'type': [0.0, 0.5289256, 1.0, 0.5, 0.52892562]
}
OG_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

OG_df

Jupyter Output:
    type
0   0.000000
1   0.528926
2   1.000000
3   0.500000
4   0.528926

OG_df_dropped = OG_df[np.abs(OG_df['type'] - 0.5289256) > 1e-7]
unique_values = OG_df_dropped['type'].unique()
print(unique_values)

[0.  1.  0.5]


When you use df.drop(), you need to use the inplace=True argument or overwrite the df. If not, your df will still have that value. Here's an example:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


x = np.array([[0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 1., 1., 0.52892562, 0., 0.],
              [0., 1., 1., 0.52892562, 0., 0.],
              [0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
print(x)
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=y)
print('Original df: ')
print(df)
indexes = df[df == 0.52892562].stack().index.to_list()
drop_these = [i[0] for i in indexes]
print('This is not inplace: ')
df.drop(drop_these)
print(df)
print('this is inplace: ')
df = df.drop(drop_these, axis=0)  # OR use: df.drop(drop_these, inplace=True)
print(df)

The output will be:
[[0.         1.         1.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         1.         1.         0.52892562 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         1.         1.         0.52892562 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         1.         1.         0.         0.         0.        ]]
Original df: 
     a    b    c         d    e    f
0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.528926  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.528926  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0
This is not inplace: 
     a    b    c         d    e    f
0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.528926  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.528926  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0
this is inplace: 
     a    b    c    d    e    f
0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

